# How to draw path between my location to destination from input

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am doing a project which use the google map. My app is about drawing a path from the location of the user from the entered destination. Here is my code.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
PlacesTask placesTask;
ParserTask parserTask;
Polyline line;
Context context;
LatLng una;
LatLng pangalawa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    context = MapsActivity.this;
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btype);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.Btype:
                    String urlTopass = makeURL(una.latitude,
                            una.longitude, pangalawa.latitude,
                            pangalawa.longitude);
                    new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

    atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);
    atvPlaces.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            atvPlaces.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
    atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            placesTask = new PlacesTask();
            placesTask.execute(s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
        String data = "";
        String key = "key=AIzaSyCob51WvrkV9qAv6hiu4x0ku6tOC1_yzXI";
        String input="";
        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String types = "types=geocode";
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {
    JSONObject jObject;
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        String[] from = new String[]{"description"};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
        atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
public void onSearch(View view){
    String location = atvPlaces.getText().toString();

    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if(location != null || location.equals("")) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng pangalawa = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pangalawa).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pangalawa));
    }
}
public void changeType(View view){
    if(mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL){
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }
    else{
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener(){
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location){
        LatLng una = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(una));
        if(mMap != null){
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(una, 16.0f));
        }
    }
};
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

public void driverDetails(){
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    detailsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(detailsIntent);
}
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    driverDetails();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;

    connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
        url = urlPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
        if (result != null) {
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}

public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat,
                      double destlog) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    return urlString.toString();
}

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}

public void drawPath(String result) {
    if (line != null) {
        mMap.clear();
    }
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pangalawa).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.b)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(una).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.b)));
    try {
        // Tranform the string into a json object
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

        for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
            line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                    .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
}
```

Am I doing the right thing? or not? When i click the button of the drawing of path the application stopped. I don't know how i will get get the lat and long of the inputted destination to autocomplete textview and the user location. I just only need to draw path from the current location of the user and from the location that inputted by the user.

Comment: If the application stopped you have to look and provide logcat, stop means an error in the app

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake. I didn't use the initialize lat long in the initialization area. Sorry. :)